# iOS 8 how to pause and resume audio in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, avaudiosession

I have looked around, and I can't seem to find out how to resume audio when the app enters background in **iOS 8**. This is what's in my app Delegate:

```
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
 @interface AppDelegate ()

 @end
 @implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
view.paused = NO;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
// Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

The problem is that when the app enters background, the audio doesn't resume playing in ios 8. It returns this error:

ERROR:

```
 [0x35ad49dc] AVAudioSession.mm:646: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
```

This problem doesn't exist in ios7. The Audio plays as an SKAction like this:

```
 SKAction *music = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"new music.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
[[self scene] runAction:music];
```

Can someone please tell me how to properly pause and resume audio in iOS8?

Comment: Have you found something? Struggling with the same. This is SpriteKit bug, I think, and the real question is: How to stop running I/O (?) opened by SKAction playFileNamed: even all the sounds finished to play a long ago? This question is vital because going background and foreground (or any other interruption) will result with dumb SK audio until we go back and forth again.

Comment: No I haven't found anything yet, perhaps this should be reported to Apple as well since this problem didn't exist in ios 7